# coloring matplotlib scatterplot by third variable with log color bar

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to make a scatterplot of two arrays/lists, one of which is the x coordinate and the other the y. I'm not having any trouble with that. However, I need to color-code these points based on their values at a specific point in time, based on data which I have in a 2d array. Also, this 2d array of data has a very large spread, so I'd like to color the points logarithmically (I'm not sure if this means just change the color bar labels or if there's a more fundamental difference.)

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)

time = #I'd like to specify time here. 

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

multi_array = [[1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], [10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1], [300, 400, 5000, 12, 47]]

for counter in np.arange(0, 5):
    t = multi_array[time, counter] #I tried this, and it did not work. 
    s = plt.scatter(x[counter], y[counter], c = t, marker = 's')

plt.show()
```

I followed the advice I saw elsewhere to color by a third variable, which was to set the color equal to that variable, but then when I tried that with my data set, I just got all the points as one color, and then when I try it with this mockup it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Could someone please help me color my points the way I need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, and using information learned from user4421975's answer and the link in the comments, I've puzzled it out. In short, I used plt.scatter's norm feature/attribute/thingie to mess with the colors and make them logarithmic.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)

time = 2 

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

multi_array = np.asarray([[1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], [10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1], [300, 400, 5000, 12, 47]])

for counter in np.arange(0, 5):
    s = plt.scatter(x[counter], y[counter], c = multi_array[time, counter], cmap = 'winter', norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=multi_array[time].min(), vmax=multi_array[time].max()), marker = 's', )

cb = plt.colorbar(s)
cb.set_label('Log of Data')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question (which I'm not at all sure off) here is the answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(1)

time = 2 #I'd like to specify time here. 

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

multi_array = np.asarray([[1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], [10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1], [300, 400, 5000, 12, 47]])
log_array=np.log10(multi_array)
s = plt.scatter(x, y, c=log_array[time], marker = 's',s=100)
cb = plt.colorbar(s)
cb.set_label('log of ...')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This was helpful, but not quite what I meant. I don't want to take the log of the data and color it, I want the color to change logarithmically. If that makes sense?

Comment: Kind of like this. [http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_log.html](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_log.html)